# Angularjs format text to vertical

Tags: angularjs

I want to use AngularJs to format the text. 
I have text like this "Backlog".
I want to format this text to:

B 
a 
c 
k 
l 
o 
g

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please have a look at the below link.

http://plnkr.co/edit/RAOTzl6PJ16F5INzOPSG?p=preview

I wrote a directive,to which you can pass any text and the result will be as vertically aligned text.

```
<text-format text='Backlog'></text-format>
```

Hope this is what you are expecting